# Str_replace Regex in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to remove the parenthesis and everything inside of it using str_detect and regex. I've found responses that assist in removing parenthesis with text inside of it and numbers but I am having issues when it comes to detecting the $ and the possibility of having a comma in the value.

I have tried the following regex \([^()]*\) which seems to work in https://regex101.com/ but when I run it on the sample code there are no changes applied to the column.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

```
Sample Data:
Example <- data.frame(Column1 = c(
  "Pineapple ($1,000)", 
  "($50,000) Roger", 
  "($1,000)", 
  "First ($100), Second ($1,000)"))

Output <- Example %>%
mutate(Column1 =  str_replace(Column1, "\([^()]*\)", ""))
```

Managed to get an output using gsub but still wondering what would be the tidyverse approach.

```
Example$Column1 <- gsub("\\([^()]*\\)", "", Example$Column1)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the last entry that has two numbers `"First ($100), Second ($1,000)"`. Which one do you want to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace_all` and add another `\` when escaping `\` in the regex.

```
library(tidyverse)
Example %>% mutate(Column1 =  str_replace_all(Column1, "\\([^()]*\\)", ""))
#          Column1
#1      Pineapple 
#2           Roger
#3                
#4 First , Second
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me how you want to deal with entries where you have more than one number. That aside and generally, a more convenient option is to use `readr::parse_number`, rather than using `stringr::str_detect`/`stringr::str_remove`. `parse_number` takes care of additional text, units and thousands separators.

If you want to keep only the first number (in the cases where there are more than one number per entry), you can do

```r
library(tidyverse)
Example %>% mutate(Column1 = parse_number(Column1))
#  Column1
#1    1000
#2   50000
#3    1000
#4     100
```

Or if you want to keep both/multiple numbers, I suggest using `separate_rows` to separate entries based on a comma followed by a whitespace, before using `readr::parse_number`.

```r
Example %>%
    separate_rows(Column1, sep = ",\\s") %>%
    mutate(Column1 = parse_number(Column1))
## A tibble: 5 × 1
#  Column1
#    <dbl>
#1    1000
#2   50000
#3    1000
#4     100
#5    1000
```

---

### Update

To separate keys and values, here is an option; please see inline comments for explanations:

```r
library(tidyverse)
Example %>%
    # Separate multiple comma-separated entries into rows
    separate_rows(Column1, sep = ",\\s") %>%
    # Swap "(value) key" > "key (value)" %>%
    mutate(Column1 = str_replace(
        Column1, "^(\\(.+\\))\\s(\\w+)$", "\\2 \\1")) %>%
    # Separate "key (value)" into columns
    separate(Column1, c("key", "value"), sep = "\\s", fill = "left") %>%
    # Parse number
    mutate(value = parse_number(value))
## A tibble: 5 × 2
#  key       value
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Pineapple  1000
#2 Roger     50000
#3 NA         1000
#4 First       100
#5 Second     1000
```

---

### Sample data

```r
Example <- data.frame(Column1 = c(
    "Pineapple ($1,000)", 
    "($50,000) Roger", 
    "($1,000)", 
    "First ($100), Second ($1,000)"))
```

Comment: Hey, I was looking to remove only the contents inside the parenthesis i.e: keeping c("Pineapple", "Roger", "", "First, Second". I was able to get the desired result using gsub("\\([^()]*\\)","", Example$Column1) but not really sure why str_replace wasn't working.

Comment: @k3r0 I'm not sure I understand your expected output. Can you please edit your main post and include how *exactly* you want your final `data.frame` to look? Please include the code/structure for the final output in a similar way to how you included the input data.

Comment: @k3r0 Pending your update, I've included an update to show how to separate keys and values.

Comment: Ive updated it: I got the output by running Example$Column1 <- gsub("\\([^()]*\\)", "", Example$Column1) but was interested in seeing what the stringr approach would be for learning purposes

Comment: Thanks for the update @k3r0; the `gsub` approach is not very clean (it has trailing whitespaces, multiple keys etc.). Please take a look at my proposed `tidyverse` solution in the update.

Answer (score 1):

If I've got your requirements correctly, a very simple base-r `gsub` will sort you out, including tidying up the stray spaces:

```
gsub(" ?\\([^()]*\\) ?", "", Example$Column1)
[1] "Pineapple"     "Roger"         ""              "First, Second"
```

I'm not sure what you mean by a "tidyverse approach": these are just regular expressions, they are not specific to a package or even to R. If you prefer to use verbose wrappers you can use `stringr::str_replace_all` with the same exact pattern.